# CPU Stress test on Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Recently I was facing query slowness on our ADX. I need to test the performance of query under a 70% CPU utilization. I am thinking of triggering some high CPU utilization queries from Logic app or ADF in order to achieve this, is it the right approach or any good approaches are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the client SDK to trigger the queries, this would likely be simpler.